# Excel search numbering +1

Tags: vba, excel

My input is: `T15RHE020 - Bergweg` and I would like to get: `T15RHE021 - Bergweg`

This is what I currently have.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim Cet

str1 = Combobox1.text
Cet = Split(str1, "-")
Cet(0) = Left(Cet(0), 6) & Format(Val(Right(Cet(0), 3)) + 1, "000")
str1 = Cet(0) & " - " & Cet(1)

volgnummer = Left(ComboBox1, 1) & Right(ComboBox2, 2) & ComboBox3.Text & str1 & " - "
```

I would like the highest number to be +1 in volgnummer.

Comment: Here if you're trying to increment alphanumeric values [See this](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=82257) It will surely help. But you should first split the string using `Split` and then increment alphanumeric string the first one and then concatenate both to get the desired result.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the code you already have? (Even if it's not working, it shows where you are at this point.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub AlpNum()
Dim str1 as String
Dim Cet

str1 = "T15RHE020 - Bergweg"
Cet = Split(str1," - ")

'Assuming a constant field width,

Cet(0) = Left(Cet(0),6) & Format(Val(Right(Cet(0),3))+1,"000") 

str1=Cet(0) & " - " & Cet(1)

Debug.Print str1
End Sub
```

Reference : [www.Ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=82257)

Comment: Thanks for your help but now I have the next problem. I have a couple of those names loaded into combobox4 and I would like to have the highest number to be +1. Can you help me out?